# FInd specific element in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to have my program that uses selenium find (and later click) on this html code:

```
<svg aria-label="Add Photo or Video" class="_8-yf5 " color="#262626" fill="#262626" height="24" role="img" viewBox="0 0 48 48" width="24"></svg>
```

What function would I use to find this specific element?
Thanks

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and ["How much research effort is expected?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a svg web element. You can locate (by xpath) like this :

```
//*[name()='svg' and @aria-label='Add Photo or Video']
```

There are basically 4 ways to click in Selenium.

I will use this xpath

```
//*[name()='svg' and @aria-label='Add Photo or Video']
```

**Code trial 1 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[name()='svg' and @aria-label='Add Photo or Video']").click()
```

**Code trial 2 :**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[name()='svg' and @aria-label='Add Photo or Video']"))).click()
```

**Code trial 3 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[name()='svg' and @aria-label='Add Photo or Video']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

**Code trial 4 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[name()='svg' and @aria-label='Add Photo or Video']")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click().perform()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

**PS :** Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this xpath

```
yourEle = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//svg[@aria-label='Add Photo or Video'])")
```

Comment: This gives me an error message: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"(//svg[@aria-label='Add Photo or Video'])"}

Comment: you are accessing the element before load, please add wait time before click/something

Comment: wait logic as per cruisepandey : WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[name()='svg' and @aria-label='Add Photo or Video']"))).click()